# Returning reference without a copy ctor

Tags: c++, c++11

Normally when a reference is returned from a function the return variable is of valuetype.

Question is it allowed that the variable is a reference variable already?

See code below. I need to read out the myObject from the iterator shared_ptr as a reference to avoid the copy ctor (which is explicitly deleted for myObject)

```
myObject& foo()
{
  for(auto iter = myMap.begin(); 
    iter != mymap.End();
    ++iter)
   {
    if(trueCondition)
    {
       //iter->second is
      // shared_ptr<myObject>
       myObject& toBeReturned= *(iter->second);

       return toBeReturned;
     }
  }

 throw std::exception("");
}
```

Comment: you can return the reference. you have to remember to properly manage lifetime of objects which references are being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely return a reference to an object that will out-live the reference.